# CSS Mark selected element's foreground color

Tags: html, css

I have this element (HTML & CSS):

[image]

Once the user select this element, I add it the following class:

```
.subjectSelected {
color: white !important;
background-color: #30a5ff;
}
```

The background color works well but the text's color doesn't change.

Here is how it looks in HTML:

[image]

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed that the text is in an `<a>` tag, and an anchor tag does not inherit `color` by default.

You can set the color on it directly:

```
.subjectSelected a { color: white; }
```

or:

```
.subjectSelected { color: white; }
.subjectSelected a { color: inherit; }
```